# Too many values to unpack python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to read two files and iterate over both of them together. Basically I'm trying to compare it line by line. 
I get an error `Too many values to unpack`

```
f1=open("C:/oc.txt")
f2 = open("C:/p.txt")
for line,line1 in f1,f2:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To iterate over the two files in sync, use `itertools.izip`:

```
for line1, line2 in itertools.izip(f1, f2):
    # do whatever
```

You might want to use `itertools.izip_longest` instead, depending on what you want to do if the two files have different numbers of lines.

`for line1, line2 in f1, f2` tries to iterate over the tuple `(f1, f2)`, not over the two files in sync.

Comment: So does izip_longest iterate over the file with larger number of lines first?

Comment: It doesn't iterate over the longer one *first*.  It still iterates in sync, giving a pair of lines at a time, one from each file.  The difference is that `izip` will stop at the end of the shorter file (leaving extra lines in the longer file unseen), while `izip_longest` will keep iterating until both files are done (filling in rows with no counterpart in the shorter file as None).  Read the itertools module documentation for a full explanation.